# Exclude Excel rows while importing to Python based on keyword

Tags: python, excel, dataframe, row

Requirement:

1. Combine all XLS files in a directory into 1 XLSX sheet
2. Only includes several columns (determined by column position eg. A, F, G)
3. But since data size is too big, I need to **exclude several rows (determined by several keywords eg. "Category", "Owner" from several columns)**

I need help on point 3.

Below is the current code.

```
import pandas as pd
import glob

path=r'C:\Users\user.name\Documents\TEST'
files_xls = glob.glob(path + "/*.xls")

df = pd.DataFrame()

for f in files_xls:
    data = pd.read_excel(f, usecols="A,F,G,H,I,L,M,Q")
    df = df.append(data)

df.to_excel("CombinedTest.xlsx")
```

Error message:

```
C:\Users\user.name\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\python.exe "C:/Users/user.name/Documents/TEST/Combine XLS.py"

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/user.name/Documents/TEST/Combine XLS.py", line 14, in <module>
    df.to_excel("CombinedTest.xlsx")
  File "C:\Users\user.name\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py", line 2181, in to_excel
    engine=engine,
  File "C:\Users\user.name\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\formats\excel.py", line 719, in write
    f"This sheet is too large! Your sheet size is: {num_rows}, {num_cols} "
ValueError: This sheet is too large! Your sheet size is: 1233080, 8 Max sheet size is: 1048576, 16384

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: Hello helegin, can you add the error code you are receiving?

Comment: _I need help on point 3_ ... can you clarify what specific problem you're facing? Any errors?

Comment: Hi everyone. Error message has been updated in the question.

Comment: Thanks for the update. "ValueError: This sheet is too large! Your sheet size is: 1233080, 8 Max sheet size is: 1048576, 16384": It seems like your combined DataFrame is still too large.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will be easier and probably faster to perform the filtering as a post processing step because if you decide to filter whilst reading then you are iteratively growing the dataframe which is not efficient.

so you should use the following code after your for loop

```
drop_list = ['Category','Owner']
df=df[~df.isin(drop_list)]
df = df.dropna()
df.reset_index(drop=True,inplace=True)

df.to_excel("CombinedTest.xlsx")
```

I hope this helps you out :)